# 'ConfigurationStoreOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer'

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm getting the following error messages:

```
error CS1929: 'ConfigurationStoreOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and the best extension method overload 'SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder>)' requires a receiver of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder'
error CS1929: 'OperationalStoreOptions' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and the best extension method overload 'SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder, string, Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder>)' requires a receiver of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder'
```

First of all, the issue is not because I don't have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, I do.

The error appears in the code below at AddConfigurationStore and AddOperationalStore. It basically doesn't recognize the UseSqlServer. Like I said, the issue is not because I don't have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.

Code:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Login";
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Logout";
})
    .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Configuration["Certificates:Default:Path"], Configuration["Certificates:Default:Password"]))
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Dayum"],
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)))
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Dayum"],
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)))
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

The following works fine:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Dayum"],
        optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));
```

My NuGet packages:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.EntityFramework" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Certs\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself from a [scaffolded project](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_entityframework.html). Apparently, UseSqlServer is under ConfigureDbContext now.

```
dotnet new is4ef
```

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(Configuration["Certificates:Default:Path"], Configuration["Certificates:Default:Password"]))
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName));
    });
```